# Finding the gradient of $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ .

Tags: calculus, derivatives, chain-rule

In *David J. Griffiths' Introduction to Electrodynamics* - Example $1.3$, the author solves the problem of

> Find the gradient of $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$ . (As in the magnitude of the position vector).

He does
$$
\nabla r = \frac{\delta r}{\delta x} \hat{x}+\frac{\delta r}{\delta y} \hat{y}+\frac{\delta r}{\delta z} \hat{z}
\tag{1}
$$
nothing wrong there, **but then he does the following**
$$
\nabla r = \frac{1}{2}\frac{2x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} \hat{x}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{2y}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} \hat{y}+\frac{1}{2}\frac{2z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}} \hat{z}
\tag{2}
$$
which I am confused as to how he got to, I can't seem to understand/find if he just manipulated any of the values: I don't understand why he makes $\delta x$ into $2{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}}$ for all dimension variables. Can someone elaborate? Thank you.

Comment: $\frac{\delta r}{\delta x}$ is the partial derivative of $r$ with respect to $x$. To calculate that he used the formula $(\sqrt{f(t)})'=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{f(t)}}f'(t)$ wich follows from the derivative of the square root and the chain rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate what was already spoke in @leoli's comment, if $g(x) = x^{1/2}$ then $g'(x) = x^{-1/2}/2$, so if $h(x) = \sqrt{f(x)} = g(f(x))$, then by chain rule,
$$
h'(x)
 = g'(f(x))f'(x)
 = \frac{f'(x)}{2\sqrt{f(x)}},
$$
as you are seeing in all your examples.